# Spring-data-JPA with foreign key reference to "UserID" within Composite Key attempting to map to column "user" instead of UserID

Tags: spring-mvc, jpa, foreign-keys, spring-data, composite-primary-key

I am attempting to connect to my database in a Spring MVC application. There are two tables. Users and Orders, Users has a primary key column: "userID", orders has a composite key from columns: "userID" and "orderID", where userID is a foreign key referencing the "userID" column in the Users table.

Here are my classes:

Order:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Orders")
@IdClass(OrderPK.class)
public class Order implements Serializable{

    private static final Long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private OrderPK orderPK;

    //other properties
    
    //no args and full args constructor

    //getters and setters

    //toString

}
```

OrderPK:

```
@Embeddable
public class OrderPK implements Serializable {
    @Column(name = "orderID")
    private Long orderID;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "userID")
    private User user;

    public OrderPK() {
    }

    public OrderPK(Long orderID, User user) {
        this.orderID = orderID;
        this.user = user;
    }

    public Long getOrderID() {
        return orderID;
    }

    public void setOrderID(Long orderID) {
        this.orderID = orderID;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof OrderPK)) return false;
        OrderPK that = (OrderPK) o;
        return Objects.equals(getOrderID(), that.getOrderID()) &&
            Objects.equals(getUser(), that.getUser());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(getOrderID(), getUser());
    }
}
```

User:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USERS")
public class User implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name="USER_SEQUENCE", sequenceName="USER_SEQUENCE")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, 
    generator="USER_SEQUENCE")
    @Column(name = "userid")
    private Long userId;

    //other properties
    
    //no args and full args constructor

    //getters and setters

    //toString
}
```

When I try to connect to the database I get the following exception:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean  with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unable to find properties (orderID, user) in entity annotated with @IdClass:com.ex.evemarketback.domain.Order
>
> ...
>
> Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unable to find properties (orderID, user) in entity annotated with @IdClass:com.ex.evemarketback.domain.Order

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using the `@EmbeddedId`, you do not need the `@IdClass` annotation:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Orders")
public class Order implements Serializable{
```

or if you want to keep the `@IdClass`:

```
// @Embeddable - no need for that
public class OrderPK implements Serializable {
    private Long orderID;
    private Long userId;

    ...
}
```

entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Orders")
@IdClass(OrderPK.class)
public class Order implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @Column(name = "orderID")
    private Long orderID;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "userId", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Long userId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "userID")
    private User user;
```